# hasManyThough returns null - Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm looking to retrieve all transactions of an event which are created by a booking. I was thinking of using a `hasManyThrough` relationship. However it returns `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Event model:

```
public function booking(){
   return $this->hasMany(Booking::class);
}
public function transaction(){
   $this->hasManyThrough(Transaction::class, Booking::class);
}
```

Booking model:

```
public function event() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
}
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function transaction(){
    return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
}
```

Transaction model:

```
public function booking() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Booking::class);
}
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

My tables look like so
[image: Events]
[image: Bookings]
[image: Transactions]

Comment: How you make your migration?

Comment: @user15070659 added photos of db

Comment: Could it be you're missing a `return` before `$this->hasManyThrough(Transaction::class, Booking::class);`?

Comment: @SidneyGijzen That was it. Silly me. I didn't notice. Thank you.